# wxGrid in wxWidgets not accessible in screen readers

Tags: c++, user-interface, accessibility, wxwidgets, screen-readers

Consider:

```
wxGrid* grid = new wxGrid(panel, -1, wxPoint( 0, 0 ), wxSize( 400, 300));
grid->CreateGrid( 5, 5);
grid->SetColLabelValue(0, _T("col0"));
grid->SetColLabelValue(1, _T("col1"));
grid->SetColLabelValue(2, _T("col2"));
grid->SetRowLabelValue(0, _T("ro0"));
grid->SetRowLabelValue(1, _T("ro1"));
grid->SetRowLabelValue(2, _T("ro2"));
```

When I run my project, the screen reader JAWS seems unable to recognize wxGrid, it only says "Grid window", but it does not read any columns or rows in it while pressing the tab key and navigating with the arrow keys. What should I do to make wsGrid accessible to JAWS and other screen readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a trivial task. You would need to change `wxGridWindow` to derive from `wxWindowAccessible` and implement its virtual methods to make this work under Windows. There is currently no accessibility support at all for the other platforms in wxWidgets.

Comment: ok then, do you know an alternative control I can use to display tabular data that is accessible? Since I cannot use wxGrid for now. Thanks

Comment: Only `wxListCtrl` -- but it's much more limited than `wxGrid`, of course.

Comment: @VZ :
Am I right that
 - widgets like wxListCtrl support accessibility because the underlying native Windows list control does support it?
 - wxGrid is a generic control which does not have accessibility implemented?

Is there a generic control in wxWidgets that does support accessibility? Then I could look at that to see what needs to be done.
The grid has a minimal accessibility support: When moving the cursor over the grid, screen readers still get some info, basically the text that is rendered in this row. Is this a Windows feature?

Comment: Yes, you're right that native controls reuse the OS accessibility support while `wxGrid` can't do this (at least under Windows, it does use native controls with GTK and under Mac, but the story with accessibility is even worse/more complicated there, unfortunately).

Comment: From looking at the sources, it seems that wxDataViewCtrl is a generic control that has accessibility support on the wx side. I will look at this and see if I can implement something for wxGrid.

Comment: A PR is online at https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/pull/24368 .
If you are willing to test, please comment there.